# Display Agent movement and Time within the Model

Tags: anylogic

I am using the following code in the agent chart at Final State to display agent movement within the system.

```
System.out.println("I came in at " + TimeIn + " and exited at " +TimeOut + " and spent " + TimeInSystem + " seconds in the system");
```

The output displayed within the console when I run the model.

[image]

I would like to display the output in the main window. I have seen example where collection is used to display output information regarding agent progress. It was not straightforward. Is it possible to explain to me how can I  display output in a text in main for accumulative agents?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use a text element you can find in the presentation palette, initially empty

and every time you want to print you can do

```
text.setText(text.getText()+"I came in at " + TimeIn + " and exited at " +TimeOut + " and spent " + TimeInSystem + " seconds in the system\n");
```